# Romans 8:16 -" τῷ πνεύματι ἡμῶν" - Is it the Holy Spirit bears witness "with" or "to" our spirit?

Tags: john, translation-philosophy, soteriology

Most English versions translate "with our spirit," while the Bishop's Bible 1558, Mace NT, Douay, Catholic Public Domain Versions, and Lamsa and Aramaic Bible in Plain English translate "to our spirit."

- What is the difference between "with" and "to" our spirits in terms of interpretation, and why does it matter?
- God's Holy Spirit bears witness that we are his children - what is the implication in terms of one's assurance of salvation? Is it a "direct and ongoing assurance of salvation, besides "I know I am saved through faith in Jesus Christ, and the Bible says so?"

**Romans 8:16**

ESV - "The Spirit himself bears witness with our spirit that we are children of God."

YLT - "The Spirit himself doth testify with our spirit, that we are children of God."

DRB - "For the Spirit himself giveth testimony to our spirit, that we are the sons of God."

LAMSA - "And this Spirit bears witness to our spirit, that we are the children of God:

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a linguistic question on conjunctions "with and to" see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with

Comment: the greek word τω is a dative case for indirect object, it's literally "to". Spirit testifies to our spirit. To is a better preposition for "testifies". Testify to;  and perhaps "witness with". (speak to and speak with are interchangeable) https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/testify

Comment: @Sam The question "What does 'with' mean in Romans 8:16?" is on this site. Possibly a duplicate?

Comment: @C.Stroud - the starting point of my question is translation issue, for "to" and "with" in Greek, in particular, will lead to diff. interpretations and applications (ref. to  #2 sub question), though there may some overlaps.  In Eng. "speak with" and "speak to" are interchangeable, but not the term to  "witness."

Comment: If your question is about...
interpretation of a specific Bible passage...
hermeneutical approaches...
**translation of Biblical texts**...
historical context (with regards to a particular text)...
source criticism...
... then this is the right place to ask. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Key to the answer is the preposition σύν compounded with the verb:

συμμαρτυρεῖ τῷ πνεύματι ἡμῶν (NA28)

The σύν changes to συμ before the μ.  The preposition σύν means *with*.  "... witness to our spirit" would be:

μαρτυρεῖ τῷ πνεύματι ἡμῶν

The idea is someone giving testimony to back up our testimony:

> συμμαρτυρέω (Soph., Thu.+) testify or bear witness with (Plut., Thes. et Romul. 6, 5, Mor. 64c; BGU 86, 40 [II AD] al.), then also gener. confirm, testify in support of someone or someth. (as early as Solon 24, 3 D.2 the prefix συν- has in the highest degree the effect of strengthening. Likewise trag.+; Pla., Hipp. Major 282B συμμαρτυρῆσαι δέ σοι ἔχω ὅτι ἀληθῆ λέγεις; X., Hell. 7, 1, 35 συνεμαρτύρει αὐτῷ ταῦτα πάντα; 3, 3, 2; Jos., Ant. 19, 154.Without dat. and w. ὅτι foll. Plut., Mor. 724D) συμμαρτυρούσης αὐτῶν τῆς συνειδήσεως Ro 2:15. συμμαρτυρούσης μοι τῆς συνειδήσεώς μου. . . ὅτι 9:1 (on the witness of the conscience Jos., C. Ap. 2, 218). τὸ πνεῦμα συμμαρτυρεῖ τῷ πνεύματι ἡμῶν ὅτι 8:16.—The mid. Rv 22:18 t.r. M-M.*
> --
> Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). *In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur* (p. 778). University of Chicago Press.

Comment: Up-voted +1. The prefix could legitimately be rendered 'together with', considering the force of it in other words, for example conception,  συλλαμβάνω, [Strong 815](https://biblehub.com/greek/4815.htm).